# Find the Xpath to get data with importxml function

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use ImportXML function in google sheets in order to bring some prices into my google sheet, how to find the correct Xpath for this ?

This is the URL: https://super.walmart.com.mx/verduras/aguacate-hass-extra-por-kilo/00000000003354

and im trying to bring the price, in this case is $39.90

I was trying this formula but im getting NA (imported content is empty)

=IMPORTXML("https://super.walmart.com.mx/verduras/aguacate-hass-extra-por-kilo/00000000003354","//*[@id="scrollToTopComponent"]/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/h4/text()[1]")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### `IMPORTXML` does not work on Javascript content

You can verify that that the URL https://super.walmart.com.mx/verduras/aguacate-hass-extra-por-kilo/00000000003354 content loads via Javascript by

- going on your Browser settings
- Disable / block Javascript

---

[image]

---

- Refresh your URL
- See the following:

---

[image]

---

So, unfortunately you cannot use `IMPORTXML` to get the content of this URL.