# Use IMPORTXML to scrape text and img url

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

https://www.autowp.ru/cadillac/elr/90868/pictures/e2xpg1
I can't figure out how to get this model of vehicle and it's image url through importxml in google sheets. In my concept you fill the url cell in sheet and you get model of the vehicle and image url in two separate cells but i can't write xpath correctly for this.

Comment: follow these steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCvXJ.gif - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73085808/5632629

Answer (score -1):

For writing the xpath of this image URL, you could try the following steps:

1. If you are using Google Chrome, you can open the developer tools (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for Windows, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on MacOS).
2. Use the "Select Elements" function ①, click on the image ②, and then move the mouse to ③.

   [image]
3. Right click, Copy > *Copy XPath*, and add `@src` to the end of the XPath.
4. Now you can get the Google Sheet formula below

   ```
   =IMPORTXML("https://www.autowp.ru/cadillac/elr/90868/pictures/e2xpg1","/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-catalogue-vehicles-pictures-picture/app-picture/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/img@src")
   ```

However, as suggested by [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) and [Find the Xpath to get data with importxml function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474154/find-the-xpath-to-get-data-with-importxml-function), **`IMPORTXML` does not work on JavaScript content**. So, in the end, the formula would give the #N/A error, and unfortunately you cannot get the model name and the image URL via `IMPORTXML` formula.